# While Loop For Table PHP

Tags: php, while-loop, html-table

I'm trying to do this in while loop PHP, number of assignments are unlimited so rowspan should also adjust itself with the number of rows, is there any proper way to do it with minimum numbers of line?

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Assignment No</th>
     <th>Student Name</th>
     <th>Assignment Marks</th>
     <th>Overall Result</th>
   </tr> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">S1</td>
      <td align="center">5</td>
      <td rowspan="3" align="center">B Grade</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">S1</td>
      <td align="center">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">3</td>
      <td align="center">S1</td>
      <td align="center">7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it fixed that `rowspan` will have `3` rows merged?

Comment: nope it depend on number of assignments, it could be 3, 5, 8 or anynumber

Comment: How is your input data formatted?

Comment: From where you will get data from database or from other source?

Comment: Try count number of assignments per students and echo it out as rowspan value.

Comment: @KevalRathi data is from database mysql

Comment: @mdamia rowspan will repeat everytime

Comment: Just to understand the requirement: if you get 8 answers, you expect  a four column table, where the last column is your rowspan, and there is a blank cell, or do you want the number of columns to vary depending on the data?

Comment: @KashifLatif, rather than using the while loop to output the html table, build you data array where the assignments are grouped by students in a variable array student, then count how many assignment per students. Use the count as rowspan value.

Comment: @JoSSte: columns are fixed and that's 4, no of rows are coming from database depend on record, they could be 3, 5 or 8 etc... now i want a rowspan in last column similar size of rows

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    <? foreach($dataarray as $data)
    {?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><? echo $data[0]; ?></td>
          <td align="center"><? echo $data[1]; ?></td>
          <td align="center"><? echo $data[2]; ?></td>
          </tr>
    <? if($data[3]!=Null) { ?>
    <td rowspan="3" align="center"><? echo $data[3]; ?></td>
    <? } ?>
    <? } ?>
```

and put if condition for last column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that data comes in a linear fashion (ie a plain one dimensional array), and that the grade is not in the array, I'd do something like this:

```
<? 
   $sizeofArray = count($data);
   $rowspan = floor($sizeofArray/3);

   for($arrCnt = 0; $arrCnt < $sizeofArray; $arrCnt +=3)
{?>
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><?=$data[$arrCnt]; ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?=(($arrCnt+1 < $sizeofArray)?$data[$arrCnt+1]:"&nbsp;"); ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?=(($arrCnt+2 < $sizeofArray)?$data[$arrCnt+2]:"&nbsp;"); ?></td>
      </tr>
<? if($data[3]!=Null) { ?>
<td rowspan="<?=$rowspan?>" align="center"><?=$grade; ?></td>
<? } ?>
<? } ?>
```

EDIT: added "padding" code, to avoid index out of bounds error

Answer (score 0):

Based on your case, rowspan is different from one student to another. What you would want to do, is group data by student. The number of assignments per student is what will give you rowspan value.

```
While ... {
  $data['student'][] =  ['name' => $row -> name]; // all student inf
  $data['student][]['assignments'][] = ['id' => $row -> assignement_id];//student assigments

}
```

Hope this help or put in the right direction to resolve your problem. 
use foreach to loop

```
foreach ($data as $student){

  $rowspan = count($student['assignments'];
  foreach ($student['assigments'] as $assignment ){
         // html table 
  }
}
```